# Getting crash report about Window Manager Bad Token Exception without own code?

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-windowmanager

I know that `WindowManager's BadTokenException` could occur when you try to show a dialog with an activity/context which is no longer available.

I take about this practice in my code greatly, since I use a lot of `async tasks`, which could contain **"dead" activites.**

For example when the app loads a screen I show a progress bar, when it finishes loading (`onPostExecute` of `async task`) I show a dialog, but **I usually check whether the activity is not dead.**

**However**, I do still get this error in crashalytics (see below)

My problem is that this code **DOES NOT CONTAIN any code of my app.** So, as far as I know it is impossible to track its place.

What can you suggest?

[image]

Comment: This is coming from a `Toast`. See this article, maybe it helps. https://proandroiddev.com/how-i-resolved-windowmanager-badtokenexception-for-toast-handleshow-2308203ebb91

Comment: This might be it, thank you. I'll try it.